# How to set products of small variables to zero

Tags: numerics, simplifying-expressions

Say I have an expression which contains different product combination of very small variables, say, `δA, δB, δC`.

I want to set all the products and all the variables with exponents greater than 1 to 0; e.g.,

```
δA δB -> 0, δA δC -> 0, δA^2 -> 0, ... etc
```

I can do so by using replace command:

```
expression /. {δA δC -> 0, ...}
```

But that is definitely not the most efficient way. Can you give me any idea on how to make it happen without listing all the possibilities?

Comment: As ever, it's easiest to post a response when given a specific example, in proper code. Absent that, I'd suggest something like `Normal[Series[expression/.Thread[vars->t*vars],{t,0,1}]]/.t->1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most efficient I can think of:

```
With[{vars = (δA | δB | δC)},
     expr /. {x: vars * y: vars -> 0, vars^n_ /; n>1 -> 0}]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! It seems to work for higher order terms but simply
    `With[{vars = (δA | δB | δC)},
     δA*δB/. {x: vars * y: vars -> 0, vars^n_ /; n>1 -> 0}]`
returns
   `δA*δB`

Comment: @YuriyIvanov I think parentheses are necessary here `(x : vars) ( y : vars)`

Comment: @ybeltukov right, that is fine now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @YuriyIvanov: Strange; for me (on Mathematica 8.0.0.0) the very expression you wrote (copy/pasted directly from your comment) evaluates to `0`.